# What's the probability that I draw at least 1 white card when drawing 3 cards from 3 decks of 15 cards, 2 of which are white?

Tags: probability, card-games

I haven't seen quite this scenario on a card drawing problem on here. I'm trying to figure out the probabilities for a card game I'm developing. There are 3 separate decks with 15 cards each. In each deck there are 2 'white cards' let's say and we're interested in drawing those. So if I draw 3 cards from each of the decks, then what is the probability that I draw at least 1 'white card' and not one of the other 13?

I think I calculated the probability for one of the decks so I'll put my work here for someone to check it.

Probability of drawing at least 1 white card when drawing 3 cards from one deck:

First, I computed the probability of drawing exactly 1 white card when drawing 3 cards from one deck, which is as follows.

$P(W_1) =  (_3C_1) \left(\frac{2}{15}\right)^1 \left(\frac{13}{15}\right)^2$
$P(W_1) = 0.3004$

Then, I computed the probability of drawing 2 white cards when drawing 3 cards from the deck.

$P(W_2) = (_3C_2)\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)^2 \left(\frac{13}{15}\right)^1$
$P(W_2) = 0.0462 $

So then the probability of drawing at least 1 white card is,

$P(W)= P(W_1) + P(W_2) = 0.3466$

So how do I go about incorporating the other 2 decks into my equation? What's the probability of drawing a white card when drawing 3 cards from each deck? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want at least one white card total? Or do you want at least one white card for every deck?

Comment: At least one white card total.

Comment: OK. In that case, there is a very quick trick using what some people call [complementary counting](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Complementary_counting). I've shown how to use this for your problem, in my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the probability of drawing **at least one white card** is the same as $1$ minus the probability of drawing **no white cards**:

$$
P\left(\text{at least $1$ white card}\right) = 1 - P\left(\text{no white cards}\right)$$

---

The probability that no white cards are drawn when taking three cards from a single deck is:

$$P\left(\text{no white cards from a single deck over three draws}\right) = \left(\frac{13}{15}\right)\left(\frac{12}{14}\right)\left(\frac{11}{13}\right)$$

---

In order to get no white cards over all nine draws, it's necessary to get no white cards on the three draws from each of the three decks:

$$P\left(\text{no white cards}\right) = \left(\left(\frac{13}{15}\right)\left(\frac{12}{14}\right)\left(\frac{11}{13}\right)\right)^3$$

---

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
P\left(\text{at least $1$ white card}\right) &= 1 - P\left(\text{no white cards}\right)\\\\
&= 1 - \left(\left(\frac{13}{15}\right)\left(\frac{12}{14}\right)\left(\frac{11}{13}\right)\right)^3 = \boxed{\frac{32227}{42875}} \approx 0.75165
\end{align*}

Comment: **Note:** This is for drawing *one* card from each deck, not for *three* cards from *each* deck".

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks for the correction - I had misunderstood the question. I've fixed the answer :)

Comment: Nice this is the method my friend used as well! Thank you for taking the time to post.

Answer (score 1):

So I was messing around with it more and talking to a friend about it. Can anyone tell me if this is correct...

$P(W) = 1 - P(W')$

$ = 1 - \left(\frac{^{13}C_3}{^{15}C_3}\right)^3 $

Which comes out to $P(W) = 0.752$

It just seems quite high to me.

Comment: That's the same answer I got for 9 cards being drawn, total